# Why this implementation of "strupr" don't work?

Tags: c, gcc

Wrong implementation (compiled with gcc):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* strupr( char *str )
{
    while(*str) {
        *str++ = toupper(*str);
    }

    return str;
}

int main(void) {

    char string[] = { "Test String!" };
    strupr( string );
    puts( string );

    return 0;
}
```

The function changes the string in an unexpected way, where the chars translated to upper case are only starting from the second char.

Note `str` is used twice in the assignment.

Comment: You don't return anything from a function with a return value, and you should really be much more specific about what doesn't work and such.  "Don't work" is rarely a useful description.

Comment: You should step through it in a debugger.

Comment: Warning serve a purpose. Pay heed to them!

Comment: Please tell us what happens.  Converts all to lower-case?  Nasal demons?

Comment: Why would you try to be too clever for yourself? Just say `*str = toupper(*str); ++str;` like a normal person...

Comment: ^^ what @KerrekSB says *1000.  Another 'clever code' disaster.

Comment: This is an interesting example of undefined behavior due to sequence points, and should not be closed.

Answer (score 3):

This implementation is invalid because it contains undefined behavior.

The explanation comes from section 6.5, paragraph 2 of the standard:

> Between the previous and next [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.

The standard gives an example of an expression that is considered undefined behavior to clarify the second sentence:

```
a[i++] = i;
```

In this expression the value of `i` is read not only to determine the new value to be stored, but also to determine the storage location of another value.

This is precisely what is happening in your expression:

```
*str++ = toupper(*str);
```

The only difference is that your expression uses pointers, and calls `toupper` in between.

This requirement may seem arbitrary, but it has a reason. C standard allows the compiler to make side effects of `++` visible before or after the call of `toupper` to allow compiler writers maximum flexibility. Without a restriction on `str`'s use in expression this could lead to different behavior on different platforms, so the standard writers decided to prohibit it outright.

Comment: I thought that a function call was a sequence point?  No?

Comment: ..though whatever, best to totally avoid any confusion and explicitly write in extra lines to make it absolutely clear what is happening.  I hate all this 'sequence point' crap.  IMHO, C would have been better off without the pre/post inc/dec operators:(

Comment: Orite, thanks.  Still hate ++/-- :)

Comment: @MartinJames `toupper` is allowed to be a macro.

Comment: There is a sequence point, the function. Can you quote the part where it is allowed to be a macro. Assuming it is a function, I think the problem is due to indeterminate sequencing of the left and right operand of the simple assignment operator.

Comment: I suspect that, whatever, we can all agree it's crap code.

Comment: @2501 It's in the section 7.1.4 of the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), bottom of page 166: "Any function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a function-like macro defined in the header"

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Interesting thanks. Could you comment on my assumption?

Comment: @2501 Sure - you are right about the situation even when `toupper` is a function, because the compiler is free to evaluate the left side and complete its side effects before invoking the right side.

Comment: If the left side is evaluated first there is ub, and if the right side is first there is no ub. Since the order is unspecified and may change during the execution of the same program (6.5.p3 (86)), I would rather count that as ub.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. The function change the string in an unexpected way, where the chars translated to upper case are only starting from the second char. I suspected the dual use of "ptr" was the culprit, but I found no way to justify why. Now I have it from the C standard (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), sequence points.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight (Sorry for the stream of comments) I think I found the text that confirm that it is undefined behavior: 6.5. p2. In short: if any of the orderings could cause ub, then the whole expression is ub.